# Checking for an existing id using Knex

Tags: javascript, express, knex.js

I am doing CRUD routes using express and Knex. For the update and delete routes, I can select the id but I am having an issue with if the id does not exist. If the id does not exist I need to show the error message and status code 400. Is there an issue with my code not reaching the catch to display the error? Do I need a conditional for ids not in the database?

I tired adding a if statement  for the conditional if the id.length === 0 but I was still getting status 200 when I tested or an id that was not in the database. I am using Postman to test for the error if I use an id not in the database.

```
//PUT update todo
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    knex('todos')
    .where({
        id: req.params.id   
    })
    .update(req.body)
    .returning('*')
    .then(todos => {
        res.status(201).json(todos[0]) 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(400).send(error)
       
    });
})

//DELETE 
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    knex('todos')
    .where({
        id: req.params.id
    })
    .del()
    .then(function() {
        
        knex.select() //select all *
            .from('todos')
            .then(function(todos){
                res.status(200)
                res.send(todos);
            })
        
    })
    .catch(error => {
       // console.log(error.message)
        
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Knex won't throw an error if no rows are updated or deleted so your `catch` block isn't going to trigger.

As you are calling the `returning` function they should return an array of objects representing what was updated/deleted though so you could inspect that to check if it is empty, i.e.

```js
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    knex('todos')
    .where({
        id: req.params.id   
    })
    .update(req.body)
    .returning('*')
    .then(todos => {
        if (todos.length) {
          res.status(201).json(todos[0]) 
        } else {
          res.status(400).send(error)
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    });
})
```